# Getting Issue in xAxis.setValueFormatter with Dynamic value :

Tags: android, kotlin, graph

**I am getting some issue Bar Graph with Dynamic values in X-Axis values setValueFormatter:**

I checked with a list view, recycler view and view inflation but always getting issues in the values in X-Axis Formatter that it doesn't work with value when list size is 3 or less than 3.

**With View Inflation:**

Requirement: I want to set the values in a graph with a set of 8. Like, If my list size is 14,

So the graph view inflates 2 times like:

If my list size is 10, it will inflate 2 times, first with 8 values of bar graph and the second graph only with 2 values. It works for the same when the list size is 9, 8 values for the first graph and 1 value for the second graph.

But the issue is that when the remaining value for the last graph is less than 4 like:

1. when the list size is 11, the remaining value is 3
2. when the list size is 25, the remaining value is 1 for the fourth graph

It gives the repeated or duplicated value in the x Axis like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49155241/70777410-b7e0e500-1da5-11ea-80f1-05920675d7ff.jpg):

Here is the issue:

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(object : IAxisValueFormatter { 
override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
var size : String = ""
try {
if(value>=0&&!mMonths[value.toInt()/10 % mMonths.size].equals("")&&value<mMonths.size*10) {
size = mMonths[0 / 10 % mMonths.size]
}
}catch (e : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
xAxis.isGranularityEnabled=false

}

               return size
            }

        })
```

Note: This will work fine when `mMonths` list size is greater than 3 as you can see in the first screenshot but it gives issues for list size 1, 2 or 3.

Source code:

```
private fun setBarChart(mList:ArrayList) {
 var calender_size: Float = 0.0f
    if(mList.

size>0){
        if(mList.size>8){
            if(mList.size/8==0){
                calender_size = (mList.size / 8).toFloat()
            }else{
                calender_size = (mList.size / 8).toFloat() + 1
            }
        }else{
            calender_size = 1f
        }
    }

    var section_variable: Int = 0
    var tillvalue: Int = 0
    var list_size: Int = 1
    allGraphs.clear()
    multiplegraphviewtmp.removeAllViews()
    for (i in 0 until Math.round(calender_size)) {
        val newLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_functionalgraph, null, false)
        multiplegraphviewtmp.addView(newLayout)
        allGraphs.add(newLayout)
        newLayout.tv_categoryname.setText(mList[0].description)
        val entriesnew = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        entriesnew.clear()
        var mMonths  : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        mMonths.clear()
        if(mList.size>8){
            if (i > 0) {
                if (mList.size / 8 == 0) {
                    list_size = (i + 1) * 8

                } else {
                    val temp = mList.size % 8
                    if ((i + 1) * 8 < mList.size) {
                        list_size = (i + 1) * 8
                    } else {
                        // section_variable = section_variable + temp
                        list_size = list_size + temp
                    }
                }
            } else {
                list_size = 8
            }
            for (j in section_variable until list_size) {
                entriesnew.add(BarEntry((tillvalue * 10).toFloat(), mList[j].percentage.toFloat()))
                mMonths.add(mList[j].itemName)
                section_variable++
                tillvalue++
            }
        tillvalue = 0
    }else{
        list_size=1
        for (j in 0 until mList.size) {
            entriesnew.add(BarEntry((tillvalue * 10).toFloat(), mList[j].percentage.toFloat()))
            mMonths.add(mList[j].itemName)
            //section_variable++
            tillvalue++
        }
        tillvalue = 0
    }

    newLayout.barChartmore.legend.isEnabled = false
    newLayout.barChartmore.description.isEnabled = false

    var leftAxisfornewgraphs = newLayout.barChartmore.getAxisLeft()
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setAxisMaxValue(100f)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setAxisMinValue(0f)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setStartAtZero(true)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setAxisLineWidth(0f)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setLabelCount(11, true)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.setDrawGridLines(true)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.axisLineColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_textColor)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.textColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_textColor)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.textSize = 12f
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.gridColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.view)
    leftAxisfornewgraphs.axisLineColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.view)
    // leftAxisfornewgraphs.setValueFormatter(MyYAxisValueFormatter()) //////////to set labels in %


    //////////////////to change Right line/////////////////
    var rightAxis = newLayout.barChartmore.axisRight
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false)
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(40, true)
    rightAxis.axisLineColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.view)

    var xAxis = newLayout.barChartmore.getXAxis()
    xAxis.textSize = 9f
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-90f)
    xAxis.textColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_textColor)
    xAxis.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    xAxis.gridColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.view)
    xAxis.axisLineColor = activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.view)
    xAxis.granularity=1f
    newLayout.barChartmore.setPinchZoom(false)
    newLayout.barChartmore.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true)
    newLayout.barChartmore.setScaleEnabled(false)
    newLayout.barChartmore.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled=false
    val labels = ArrayList<String>()
    labels.clear()
    for (i in 0 until mMonths.size){
        labels.add("18-Jan")
    }
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(object : IAxisValueFormatter {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            var size : String = ""
            try {
                    if(value>=0&&!mMonths[value.toInt()/10 % mMonths.size].equals("")&&value<mMonths.size*10) {
                        size = mMonths[0 / 10 % mMonths.size]
                        mTotalvalues++
                    }
                }catch (e : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
                    xAxis.isGranularityEnabled=false
                }

            return size
        }

    })
    xAxis.spaceMin = 6f
    xAxis.spaceMax = 6f

    val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entriesnew, "Cells")
    barDataSet.setDrawValues(false)

    val list: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()
    list.clear()
    list.add(activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_skyblue))
    list.add(activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_orange))
    list.add(activity!!.resources.getColor(R.color.graph_navyBlue))

    barDataSet.setColors(list)
    val data = BarData(barDataSet);
    if(mMonths.size<2){
        data.barWidth= 1f
    }else{
        data.barWidth= 5f
    }
    newLayout.barChartmore.data = data
    newLayout.barChartmore.invalidate()
    newLayout.export_single.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Commonclass.createPdf(activity, newLayout.barChartmore.chartBitmap)
    })
    //newLayout.barChartmore.clear()

}
}
```

Same Issue getting with recycler view and Listview. please help:

Answer (score 0):

I am getting some issue Bar Graph with Dynamic values in XAxis values setValueFormatter